# Less multiple classes rules using parent selector

Tags: css, less

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block--is-disabled block--is-focused">Block</div>
</div>
```

And some LESS code:

```
// LESS
.block {
  &--is-disabled {
    // some styles
  }

  &--is-focused {
    // some styles
  }
}
```

Is it possible to apply styles like `.block--is-disabled.block--is-focused` using LESS parent selectors? The only thing I've reached is:

```
// LESS 
.block {
  &--is-focused & {
    &--is-disabled {
      // some styles
    }
  }
}
```

With the following CSS output:

```
.block--is-focused .block--is-disabled {
  // some styles
}
```

But what I need to get is the next CSS:

```
.block--is-disabled.block--is-focused {
  // some styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
.block {
    &--is-focused&--is-disabled {
        ...
    }
}
```